# Insert data when user is registering

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

Say me please, I need insert in some table `userId` and `some hash`, when user registering on my site.

How can I do this?

As I understand I need to use events, but I have not figured out how can I use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try answer for you step-by-step mode.

1) In model `User` in method `afterSave` add this:

```
public function afterSave()
    {
        $this->trigger('event_name');
        parent::afterDelete();
    }
```

2) Add in model `User` new method:

```
public function init()
    {
        $this->on('event_name', ['app\models\SOME_MODEL', 'someMethod']);            
    }
```

3) In `SOME_MODEL` add `someMethod` code like that:

```
    public static function someMethod($event)
        {
            /** @var \yii\base\Event $event */
            /** @var ActiveRecord $event->sender */
            $userId = Yii::$app->user->id;
// some code to add in table or send to email
            $model = new Logs([
                'type' => $event->sender->getType(),
                'action' => $event->name,
                'id_user' => $userId,
                'old_data' => Json::encode($event->sender->attributes),
                'new_data' => Json::encode($event->sender->oldAttributes),
            ]);
            $model->save();
        }
```